# Does a lock around a closure also protect the contents of the closure?

Tags: c#, locking

Suppose I have the following code:

```
lock (this.myLock)
{
  this.myTimer = new Timer(_ =>
  {
    this.myConcurrentlyAccessedInt += 1;
  }, null, 1000, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

Will `myLock` protect `myConcurrentlyAccessedInt`?

*Side note:* I know that for this use case `Interlocked` is what I should use. I'm just using this simple example as a way to explore the semantics of a `lock` wrapping a closure. My guess is that it would not protect `myConcurrentlyAccessedInt`, but I'd like to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lock` keyword itself wouldn't protect any variables.

What `lock` does is allowing one thread to enter and execute the following statement block.

As per @Enigmativity made it clear in the comments:

> The only way a lock works is if all access to a variable is protected by a lock.

In your case, `myConcurrentlyAccessedInt` is **not** protected by `myLock`, because increment does not happen in a statement protected by `myLock`.

To get `myLock` to protect `myConcurrentlyAccessedInt`, you will need to read and write `myConcurrentlyAccessedInt` only in statements protected using `myLock`.

For example, in the code below, `myConcurrentlyAccessedInt` is protected by `myLock`:

```
lock(myLock)
{
    this.myTimer = new Timer(_ =>
    {
        lock(myLock)
        {
            this.myConcurrentlyAccessedInt += 1;
        }
    }, null, 1000, Timeout.Infinite);

    this.myTimer2 = new Timer(_ =>
    {
        lock(myLock)
        {
            this.myConcurrentlyAccessedInt -= 1;
        }
    }, null, 1000, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

Comment: This is unclear and ambiguous. Only paragraph two is clear. Paragraph 1 is wrong as it protects the `myTimer` variable. And your third paragraph suggests that statements in the `lock` are protected - `myConcurrentlyAccessedInt ` appears in the source code to be in the `lock` so you're saying it should be protected?

Comment: @Enigmativity how would lock protect `myTimer`? Can't you modify the timer from another thread while it is in a lock statement?

Comment: That's true of any variable within a `lock`. The only way a `lock` works is if all access to a variable is protected by a `lock`.

Comment: Your third point is correct if you know what statements are in the `lock` and those which are not. The OP clearly doesn't understand that. You haven't said anything to clear up that confusion. And that's the crux of my point.

Comment: @Enigmativity That's true. What about the revised version now?